# problem installing canonTS9020 on Pi3-b+

Tags: pi-3b+, printing

I'm new to the rasberryPi / linux scene and need suggestions.

After running the command below & launching cups 2.2.1
I can see a list of printers after pressing the "add printer" button as shown here:

```
Local Printers:  VNC Remote Printer (VNC Printer)
 HP Printer (HPLIP) 
 Canon TS9000 series (Canon TS9000 series)
 HP Fax (HPLIP) 
Discovered Network Printers:     Canon TS90202 (Canon TS9000 series)
 Canon TS9000 series 2.010 (Canon TS9000 series)
Other Network Printers:  Backend Error Handler 
 Internet Printing Protocol (ipp14) 
 AppSocket/HP JetDirect 
 Internet Printing Protocol (ipp) 
 LPD/LPR Host or Printer 
 Internet Printing Protocol (ipps) 
 Internet Printing Protocol (http) 
 Internet Printing Protocol (https)
```

You can see in "Discovered Network Printers:" that it has found 2 printers on the network.

If I select the " Canon TS9000 series 2.010 (Canon TS9000 series) " printer
it does have "socket://192.168.0.157"  - great, so far so good !

The issue occurs after I press the "continue" button
i receive an enormous/huge list of canon printers but none of these have the TS series.
I have tried in vain for a week trying ones with simular names, hoping one might work.
FYI,
I did download and read the entire gutenprint manual but I am not knowledgeable enough to compile/build my own print drivers.

Which is why i ran:
apt-get install printer-driver-gutenprint

Comment: Canon has a Linux [compatibility page](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/operating_system_information/#LIX) you might want to check.

Comment: Welcome.  There's no guarantee there is a driver available regardless of what you do -- Canon does not really support the platform.

Comment: because i never was able to get the above installation working, i decided to remove CUPS. Then reinstalled CUPS and downloaded Turbo Print 2 for Linux from their website. What a nice piece of software, beautiful user interface. Best of all there is a 30 trial period with no upfront purchase required !*****Problem Fixed.